# relative path of image to byte array in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, image

i have relative path of an image as

```
~/image/noimage.jpg
```

i wants to read byte array to save in database if that organization's logo is not in db

```
public byte[] org_logo(int myOrgId)
    {
        byte[] photo ;
        var context = new mp_repositoryEntities();
        var query = from o in context.organizations 
                    where o.organization_id == myOrgId
                    select o.logo;            
        photo = query.FirstOrDefault<byte[]>();
        if (photo == null)
        {
            photo = File.ReadAllBytes("~/image/noimage.jpg");
        }
        return photo;
    }
```

when i am setting this path to asp image control then it is working fine.

```
logo.ImageUrl = "~/image/noimage.jpg";
```

any idea ?????

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`File.ReadAllBytes` is not an asp.net api, so the leading ~ means nothing to it. Instead, try:

```
string path = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/image/noimage.jpg");
photo = File.ReadAllBytes(path);
```